# Cannot start phpmyadmin

Tags: apt, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I cannot start my apcahe2 and phpmyadmin in my VPS.

```
$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin    
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done   
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.   
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:   
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or   
                       php5-mysqli but it is not installable or   
                       php5-mysqlnd but it is not going to be installed   
              Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed   
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you tried to install `php5-mysql`?

Comment: @tkausl sudo apt-get install php5-mysql

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a problem when installing packages from external sources (i.e. from a *deb file) when a package from ubuntu repository is available.
You can get more information by running aptitude (but you might need to install it first, it doesn't come with default ubuntu)

usually removing the non-official package (with `apt-get remove phpmyadmin` and then installing the official one (with `apt-get install phpmyadmin`) is the way to un-hold packages.

also, `apt-get install --fix-missing` will try to fix all the missing packages, which should also solve your missing packages that "are not going to be installed"

I think this is fixed automatically if there is only one level of packages holding the package you're trying to install. if there's more levels (i.e. php5-mysql requires something else) I really think you should use aptitude to help you solve the missing packages (because as long as you're reading what it offers, you should be able to pick the correct resolution)